# Weird issue with applications not responding on Macbook

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, finder, google-chrome

I have a MacBook Pro 2017 15 inch with macOS Catalina. It's up to date and I have freed up more disk space.

Anyway, my issue is weird and I haven't been able to fix it nor find anyone who's had it. Basically, sometimes, whenever I perform any one of a set of actions, the application will freeze, ill get the spinning wheel, and the application does not respond ("Application is not responding"), I try force-quitting and that fixes the freeze, but then it will happen again if I do the action again. I have noticed the issue on XD, Chrome, Safari and Finder.

So, the actions are for example: cmd+c on Chrome, cmd+r on Chrome, trying to select a image from finder in Chrome, trying to edit text or cmd+c on XD, trying to delete or move a file to another folder on Finder, highlighting text on System Information, trying to open a link in new tab on Safari.

And when there is an issue with one of them, (e.g. try to copy on chrome and chrome freezes), then if I go onto XD and try to edit text I will also get the freeze. However, weirdly, some actions like cmd+c dont cause issue on Slack, however attaching/selecting a file from "Your computer" (through Finder) does cause the Not responding issue. And so, what's weird is that then I have to try and restart and force-quit all applications, and re-launch Finder etc., it is an arduous task to try and fix it. But when it is fixed then all applications will work, until randomly it starts freezing each application when doing those actions I mentioned before.

Note that the issue may also happen on other applications and with other actions, but those are the only ones I've noticed so far.

This issue is extremely annoying, and has been frustrating me for months now, with no fix yet! Lately, it's been happening more frequently and is harder to fix (as in I have to do many restarts, many shut downs, sometimes SMC resets etc. to make the issue go away)

**PLEASE HELP!**

Comment: the issues are unique to each application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue in the MacOS software. I have now fixed it by reinstalling the MacOS on my computer. No issues now!